# How can I autoplay media in iOS >= 4.2.1 Mobile Safari?

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, ios, mobile-safari

I cannot seem to get audio media to play in Mobile Safari on iOS 4.2.1 in any situation other than the handler of a click event performed by the user.  Even then, if `player.play()` is called in any asynchronous fashion (`ajax, setTimeout`, etc) it doesn't work.

I've tried calling `player.load()` before `player.play()`. I've tried triggering a click event on a dom element whose handler calls `player.play()`. I've tried using both audio and video tags.

All the loopholes that worked prior to iOS 4.2.1 seem to be closed. Any ideas?

Comment: Pretty sure that’s by design. Some of your users may be on cell plans that charge by data usage, and they don’t want your media to auto-play.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autoplay an Audio File on Mobile Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841966/autoplay-an-audio-file-on-mobile-safari)

Comment: I understand it's by design. However, prior to 4.2.1 there were several loopholes that allowed circumvention. FWIW, I'm not actually trying to autoplay audio on page load. The audio source urls I'm using are unstable and cannot be cached, so I'm making an ajax call inside the click handler to resolve the audio source.  This in itself is enough to trigger iOS's defense mechanisms apparently.

Comment: I spent about an hour today shuffling code around because I had the `play()` function within an asynchronous function (Ajax call).  Even in a click handler, with an actual click, it still didn't work.  So: beware, I guess.  I wish Apple would publish the specific criteria we need to follow.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Starting from iOS 4.2.x, the download of media will not be started if there isn’t a user-input event, like touchstart.

So the answer is **no**, there is no method to autoplay media by JavaScript or something else.

Comment: Any official links from Apple saying this? Just to satisfy the higher ups ;) Thanks!

Comment: azure_ardee - see this http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1

Comment: @ArdeeAram This link from Apple explains how video with audio not muted can't be autoplayed without user interaction. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/safari_tools_and_features/delivering_video_content_for_safari

Answer (score 14):

There is one way to play the video/audio file automatically on 4.2.1. Create an iframe and set its source to the media file's URL and append the iframe to the body. It'll be autoplay.

```
var ifr=document.createElement("iframe");
ifr.setAttribute('src', "http://mysite.com/myvideo.mp4");
ifr.setAttribute('width', '1px');
ifr.setAttribute('height', '1px');
ifr.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');
ifr.style.border="0px";
document.body.appendChild(ifr);
```

Comment: works fine for audio, but video player is not loaded on the iPhone

Comment: I can confirm that this works on the iPad, but it seems to force a reload of a sound each time that it it played. Are there any workarounds that allow it to cache the sound, so that it gets played instantly.

Comment: GREAT! It works! Tested on iOS 4.3.5 (iPod Touch 4). No loop, BTW.

Comment: Also, if you create 2 iframes, only the last one really plays.

Answer (score 6):

As others have said here and according to Apple documentation, MobileSafari does NOT support the autoplay attribute in the video tag. However, in iOS 6 it DOES work. This appears to be a bug which Apple fixed in iOS 6.0.1 (and presumably in iOS 6.1).

Don't rely on autoplay working in iOS 6 if you happened to stumble across it working in iOS 6.0.

-Michael

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, I tried tying the load()/play() code to a click event, and then triggering the click event programmatically.  This approach worked in Desktop Safari, but not Mobile Safari.

Answer (score 1):

This worked on the iPad until last nights 4.2 upgrade:

```
$(function() {
    var Beep = document.createElement('audio');
    Beep.setAttribute('src', 'beep-23.mp3');
    Beep.load();
    Beep.play();
}
```

My `Beep.play();` still works for a click event, but the initial `Beep.play()` stopped working...

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

Create an audio sprite with Sound Manager 2, preload & cache it from the first user interaction, and then play as and when needed.

Would that work?

Comment: Unfortunately, this requires you to stop the sound, and then play so won't work. The answer above is right. There is no way :/

Comment: It works!!! Only the first sound needs to be linked to a user interaction, any subsequent sounds following can be played automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Autoplay is supported (in my tests) with an iPhone 5 (iOS 6) using the headphone jack.

Answer (score 0):

On my 3rd-gen iPad running IOS 6, autoplay of HTML5  tags has suddenly begun working!  (I've had IOS 6 installed for a couple of weeks, and am pretty sure I tested this feature right away, but only noticed it working tonight.)  I don't recall seeing any notice of this from Apple, although I did see that mobile Safari had been granted the ability to support file uploads via

```
<form><input type="file" .../></form>
```

-- another feature I needed but which Apple had withheld.

Comment: Surprised by the downvotes. This was an accurate and useful answer because autoplay did work in iOS 6. Helpful to me since it explained why I was pulling my hair out transitioning from 6.0 to 6.0.1 (see [Micheal Johnston's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13483720/1110547) for more specifics).

Answer (score -1):

Please Try this Code it is working both version, you need to add the audio control dynamically in page. it is working.

```
var isiPad = false;
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)) { 
    isiPad = true; 
}
$(function() { 
    if (isiPad) { 
        var audioElement2 = document.createElement('audio'); 
        audioElement2.setAttribute('src', 'img/bgsound.mp3'); 
        audioElement2.controls = true; 
        audioElement2.loop = true; 
        audioElement2.load();
        audioElement2.play();
    }
});
```