# Media autoplay in iOS 4.2+: How to access Quicktime through JS when using an iframe for autoplay

Tags: javascript, ios, quicktime, autoplay

There seems to be only one way to get media to autoplay in iOS versions greater than 4.2, as shown by user bhup here: [How can I autoplay media in iOS >= 4.2.1 Mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259928/how-can-i-autoplay-media-in-ios-4-2-1-mobile-safari/4449793#4449793)

```
var ifr=document.createElement("iframe");
ifr.setAttribute('src', "http://mysite.com/myvideo.mp4");
ifr.setAttribute('width', '1px');
ifr.setAttribute('height', '1px');
ifr.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');
ifr.style.border="0px";
document.body.appendChild(ifr);
```

Using this method has one major drawback: I can't find a way to get JS interacting with the Quicktime plugin when using this method.

I have tried many things, but can't find a way to both instantiate the plugin in a way that exposes it to JS and have it autoplay.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

In your iFrame element, set `onload="parent.someFunction();"`

Then, in someFunction():

```
pluginElement = document.getElementById('yourIframeElementId').contentWindow.document.body.firstChild;
pluginElement.GetTime(); //Or any other function that the QT plugin exposes
```