# Auto play in iPad apps using HTML 5

Tags: ios, html, video, mobile-safari

I want too auto play the video in my iPad apps developed using HTML 5. I tried something from the net but that is not supporting in the iOS 4 and above.

Please support us in sorting ut this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I autoplay media in iOS >= 4.2.1 Mobile Safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259928/how-can-i-autoplay-media-in-ios-4-2-1-mobile-safari)

Answer (score 2):

If you are inside a UIWebView you can try to use

```
webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false;
webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
```